# cocoa add category for system service

Tags: macos, cocoa, categories

I made a cocoa app that provides a service in the "service menu" when the mouse is right clicked, but in system preferences the app is showing app in the "general" category of available services, I want my app to show up in the "development" category of services.

My app changes the permission of a file making it executable or non executable.

Is my app a "Utility" or a "Development Tool"?

Here is my ".plist" file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>kyle.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string>public.app-category.utilities</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>${MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright © 2013 Kyle kersey. All rights reserved.</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainMenu</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>NSServices</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
            <string>public.app-category.utilities</string>
            <key>NSMenuItem</key>
            <dict>
                <key>default</key>
                <string>Toggle Executable</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSMessage</key>
            <string>handleServices</string>
            <key>NSPortName</key>
            <string>Toggle Executable</string>
            <key>NSSendFileTypes</key>
            <array/>
            <key>NSSendTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSFilenamesPboardType</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Are you asking for an opinion on which category it should go in? If so, I'm not sure what would make such an app a dev tool; sounds like a utility.

Comment: @farski first I am asking how to set the app category then i am asking what should be it's category.